# How to detect from the server ( classic asp ) that a request was cancelled?

Tags: asp-classic

I am developing a web application in classic asp, promptly the problem I'm having is related to a progress bar. I am doing some operations with the database that are too heavy, so in the middle of each iteration in the calculation, I'm doing a flush reporting the progress.

This page it's being called by an iframe and depending on the content we are updating  the progress bar. The problem is that if I delete this iframe (and concecuentemente cancel the request), I can not navigate through the site until the end of the expensive operation.

Given this situation, I have two questions:

1. As from the server (asp page) how can I can detect when the request was cancelled?
2. What can I do to enable multi threading sessions?

Comment: As for #2, classic ASP has only a single thread per user you can't create more threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can detect if the user is still connected with **Response.IsClientConnected**. So you can add this to your long running code, eg:

   ```
   If Not Response.IsClientConnected Then
       'Stop processing
   End If
   ```
2. Not sure about this. Is it only the one user who started the request that is effected or do all users have to wait? There may be a setting in IIS (you could try disabling HTTP keep alive, but it's just a guess).

Comment: about answer one, you solved my problem!!! thank you very much!
about two, it was the same user who started the request, I think is something releated to the session!